# Codeigniter create new textfield on button/link click

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm trying to make a request form for my website, and I need a button that can add new input fields on click but I have no idea on how to tackle this.

imagine this:

[ button ]

a button that when you click it, it will then create a new textfield,
and when you click it multiple times it would look something like the thing below.

[ textfield ]

[ textfield ]

[ textfield ]

[ textfield ]

Comment: I've tried absolutely nothing... I really have no idea on how to achieve this. I'm kinda new with codeigniter and php.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this

```
<form action="test.php" method="post" id="form">
<input type="text" name="id">
<input type="submit">
</form>
<button id="add">Add</button>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
var i = 1;
$('#add').click(function(){
    var newEl = '<input type="text" placeholder="Text Field '+(i+1)+'" name="'+(i++)+'"><br />';
    $('#form').prepend(newEl);
});
</script>
```

```html
<form action="test.php" method="post" id="form">
    <input type="text" name="id">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
<button id="add">Add</button>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var i = 1;
    $('#add').click(function(){
        var newEl = '<input type="text" placeholder="Text Field '+(i+1)+'" name="'+(i++)+'"><br />';
        $('#form').prepend(newEl);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: oh nice thanks! for the answer, but can I ask how can I set it so that the new field would appear at the bottom of the textfield instead of the top?

Comment: Use `append()` instead of `prepend()`.

Comment: ahh so thats what prepend does. Thanks again for the answer!. I would upvote your answer if i could but i don't have enough reputation to do it.